# Can you store a table field within a matrix field?

Tags: matrix, craft3, table-field

I am looking to use a matrix field for my site navigation that has some dropdowns. Using a table field within a matrix field seems like it would work but I don't know how to access the table inside the matrix field in my template. Is this possible.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. You can do it. Here is my example.

```
{% for block in mainNavigation.navigationLink %}
            <a class="navbar-item {{ block.className }}" href="{{ block.linkUrl }}">
                {{ block.linkName }}
            </a>

                {% if block.childLinks | length %}
                <div class="navbar-dropdown is-boxed">
                    {% for row in block.childLinks %}
                        <a class="navbar-item" href="">{{ row.childLinkName }}</a>
                     {% endfor %}
                </div>
                 {% endif %}


        {% endfor %}
```